# Error Code: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1) inside sp

Tags: mysql

i have some troubles filling a predefined table with a stored procedure. 
mytable has 6 fields: uid,testrun,exp1,exp2,exp3,weightedvalue where uid is an autoincrement PK. My sp contains an insert statement like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN testrun INT)
BEGIN
.... some declare statements ... 
INSERT  INTO exp_factors(testrun,exp1,exp2,exp3,weightedvalue) VALUES
(testrun, 
 exp1,
 exp2_1 + exp2_2,
 exp3_1 + exp3_2,
 exp1 * 0,2 + (exp2_1+exp2_2) * 0.5 + (exp3_1+exp3_2) * 0.3);


END
```

Unfortunately this results in the error stated in the title. I understand that I insert only 5 of 6 fields but obviously I do not want to enter the autoincrement PK uid manually.
How can I enter my exp values to this table without passing on the autoincrement id.
Of course I could just create a table without an extra PK, but that´s not what i want.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a comma in the last line of your insert, making 6 columns instead of 5:

```
exp1 * 0,2 + (exp2_1+exp2_2) * 0.5 + (exp3_1+exp3_2) * 0.3
        ^
```

I guess that this should be a decimal point, not a comma.

Comment: thx mike. sorry everybody. I just had the wrong decimal delimiter here.. Sometime I really MySQL workbench where you really can hardly distinguish point from comma. I am glad i c&p the code. Reminds me of a some of favorite tshirts : thanks mike :)

Answer (score 3):

The above exception is thrown when the number of columns in the insert statement is lesser than the number of values in the query

for example

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (PERSON_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,GENDER,BIRTH_DATE,CITY,STATE,COUNTRY,POSTAL_CODE) VALUES (NULL,'JHON','DOE','M','1988-06-17','7TH CROSS','HERE','THERE','WHERE','5600012');
```

Here the the number of values is 10 but the no of columns in the query is 9 thus the database throws the above exception.

to solve the problem we have to add **STREET** column to the query

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (PERSON_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,GENDER,BIRTH_DATE,STREET,CITY,STATE,COUNTRY,POSTAL_CODE) VALUES (NULL,'PRAVEEN','KUMAR','M','1988-06-17','7TH CROSS','BANGALORE','KARNATAKA','INDIA','560078');
```