# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in MySQL Update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I can't explain this issue because i don't know whats wrong...

Here is my table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| u_id         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| UA           | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| IP           | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Cookie       | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ConnectionID | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp    | int(15)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my query for MySQL

```
UPDATE u_jar 
SET u_id = 13, `timestamp` = 1460040908 
WHERE cookie = '64b2b43e343855019fecf6c89751f884'
```

and I'm getting

> Column *count* doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I feel like we're only getting half the story.

Comment: mysql says that you must give it one more field. I think it is ConnectionID, because it can't by null

Comment: Can you please add your table structure with sample data here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1) inside sp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185217/error-code-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1-inside-sp)