# sql database is giving me this error

Tags: mysql, sql

> Error Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 136) SQL query:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `zkb58_assets` ( 
>   `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', 
>   `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT )
> ```
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 4

Comment: Maybe check if the missing space between `'0'` and `COMMENT` is not doing anything funny... As well as the fact that your last `COMMENT` is not followed by any string.

Comment: Can you use COMMENT statement without comment string?

Comment: Side note: a column does not become a primary key just because you say so in a comment. It'd be better to declare it as such (which would also render the comment unnecessary).

Comment: So i removed comment and here i got another magical issue, linked below

Comment: It is not magical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185217/error-code-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1-inside-sp (see also my comment below).

Comment: BTW. Please change the question title to something more meaningful.

Comment: Negative on the string. also, my code ,seems way off

Comment: @kpater87 do you think i should add a string to this line

Comment: It is a good practice to have comments on the tables and tables columns.

Answer (score 0):

you added a comment keyword without comment
it should be like that

```
CREATE TABLE `zkb58_assets` ( 
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', 
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0')
```

Comment: So i did this fix, and it gave me this

Error
SQL query:


INSERT INTO `zkb58_assets` VALUES(1, 0, 1, 651, 0, 'root.1', 'Root Asset', '{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core.login.admin":{"6":1},"core.login.offline":{"6":1},"core.admin":{"8":1},"core.manage":{"7":1},"core.create":{"6":1,"3":1},"core.delete":{"6":1},"core.edit":{"6":1,"4":1},"core.edit.state":{"6":1,"5":1},"core.edit.own":{"6":1,"3":1}}')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: You are trying to insert the values into 6 columns, but in the table definition you have only two.